# Trouble unlocking disk due to keyboard layout

Tags: boot, grub2, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dvorak

im new to Linux, so i do apologize if im not explaining this well.

using Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-43,45, and 46.
gnu grub 2.02.

while trying to unlock disk sda5_crypt, every time i hit a number key it switches from the gui to lui, here is what happens when i hit the number 1 key, it displays this.

> WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmeted. Falling back to device scanning.
>
> Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found.
>
> Cannot prosscess volume group ubuntu-vg.
>
> Please unlock disk sda5_crypt***

note i only hit the number 1 key but 3 characters appear after the unlock disk field, i can backspace or keep typing and nothing happens unless i hit a number key again, when i do it switches back to the gui and there will be 6 characters in the password field.

i tried switching to an older kernel in grub but the same thing happens.
then i tried in recovery mode and got the same message as above only in the lui and now the only key that works is Enter. so i hit enter until it says

> maximum number of tries exceeded.
>
> cryptsetup: going to sleep for 60 seconds...

now the keyboard works but its in the Dvorak layout and when i hit a number key (number 1 for example) it shows up as

> ^[[4~

any help would be great.

i have some folders on this device i dont want to lose, so could i somehow image the disk onto a drive so i can reinstall ubuntu and work on this issue as i have time, just so i dont lose anything?

thanks.

Comment: I would firstly try using a very-standard keyboard to unlock. I have two keyboards (a logitech & a microsoft) I cannot use to unlock some of my systems because they send unusual keystrokes (for some keys) which is mis-interpreted early in the boot process (inc. unlocking encryption). The keyboards (intended for windows) expect 'drivers' to get them to be treated as normal (and enable special features).  You should also tell us your release of Ubuntu (that kernel is used by 16.04 LTS with HWE, and by 18.04 LTS)